# Here HDLM in Matlab, App ID and App code credentials validation

Tags: matlab, credentials, id

I created a Freeminum account in Here technologies website and generated the App ID and App code. I tried to use those credentials in the HERE HDLM feature in the Automated driving Toolbox in Matlab.

However, when I plug in the given information in Matlab box it gives me a

> Unable to validate credentials

message. No issues from Mathworks end.
What could be the right fix for the issue?